# How to add in JLabel array

Tags: java, jlabel

I don't know what to do. Please help me

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

    public class Sample{
    static JLabel label[];
    static int count = 0;

      public static void main (String [] args){
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample");
      JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
      JButton bt = new JButton("Okay");
      frame.setSize(800,600);
      frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.add(tf);
      frame.add(bt);


      bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
          int sum = count++;
          String getTF = tf.getText();
          label[count] = new JLabel(getTF);
        }
    });
      }
}
```

It says NullPointerException. How do I add `getTF` to `label[]`? I am confused and I can't find the right answer someone might have something for me.

Comment: You never initialized your `label` array of `JLabel` objects .

Answer (score 3):

You have not initialized your array:

```
static JLabel label[];   // "label" reference is null
```

You need to initialize it with an actual array object, e.g. like

```
static JLabel label[] = new JLabel[10];
```

However, this will then have a fixed array size (10 in this case). You will not be able to add more than 10 elements to that array.
You should use an `ArrayList` instead which is a dynamically growing array:

```
static List<JLabel> label = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then add your new label like

```
label.add(new JLabel(getTF));
```

Besides that, you should use `static` fields only if absolutely necessary - better create an instance of your application class and make the fields non-static.

You should also remove the wild card imports (like `java.util.*`) and only import those classes and interfaces which you require (like `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList`). Otherwise you might get name clashes (like between `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List`)

Comment: It says reference to List is ambigous. What do i do?

Comment: That is because you import `java.awt.*` and `java.util.*` - both have a `List` class/interface. The correct solution would be to remove the wild card imports and only import those classes which you need. (For an immediate solution, you could also use `static ArrayList<JLabel> label = new ArrayList<>();` but I prefer to use the more generic type/interface, like `List`)